# How do I suppress the warning "Command \@endpbox has changed." caused by loading the cellspace package?

Tags: packages, warnings, cellspace

Here is my MWE (LuaLaTeX):

```
\documentclass[%
% draft,
twoside,
DIV=15, % division factor
BCOR=12.5mm, % binding correction
]{scrbook} % 11pt, a4paper (default)
\usepackage[
automark,
% footheight=18pt
]{scrlayer-scrpage} % KOMA-script package for headers, footers, pagestyles
\usepackage{setspace}\setdisplayskipstretch{} % For spacing
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{microtype} % Microtypography
\usepackage{lipsum, blindtext} % For lorem ipsum dummy texts
\usepackage{mathtools, amsthm, amssymb} % Math packages
\usepackage{physics} % Physics package
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math} % Math fonts
\usepackage{array} % For arrays
\usepackage[math]{cellspace} % For array spacing
\usepackage{nicematrix} % For tabulars, arrays, and matrices

\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing
\KOMAoptions{DIV=current}
\lipsum[1-7][1-94]
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

After compiling, I receive this warning :

```
Command \@endpbox has changed.
Check if current package is valid.
```

or

[image: Warning]

How do I remove / suppress this warning that occurs when loading the [`cellspace`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cellspace?lang=en) package? Thank you.

Comment: the warning is correct, the package needs to be updated to match the current definition (specifically `\par` needs adding so the line looks like `\CheckCommand*{\@endpbox}{\@finalstrut \@arstrutbox \par\color@endgroup \egroup \hfil}` This has aleady been raised with the author of the package https://github.com/JosselinNoirel/cellspace/issues/4

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see, thank you.